# Plot errorbars on basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot errorbars on a hammer projection of the whole sky. I want to show where a vector points on the sky, with its associated uncertainties. Trying basemap.errobars like pyplot.errorbars doesn't work though. Has anyone else tried to do this?